# If contains text and numbers

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, numbers, formula

I have an Excel formula where I check if the value is above or below a certain threshold. My list contains both numbers and text.

```
Example:
Column A
10
20
30
No value
40
50
```

I want to group all the values >=30 "Above 30",the ones between 30 and 10 "Between 30 and 10" and "No value" and 10 in "Below 10".

This is the formula that I use:
=if(A1>=30,"Above 30", IF(A1<10,"Below 10","Between 30 and 10))

Everything is okay with the numbers but "No value" is marked as "Above 30".

What could be the reason for that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think you want (a) another double quote and (b) to combine (OR) the case where under 10 or Text:

```
 =IF(OR(ISTEXT(A1),A1<10),"Below 10",IF(A1>=30,"Above 30","Between 30 and 10"))
```

The OR needs to be first to take advantage of IF's short circuiting.

Excel sorts (ascending) any Text after any Number.